# Is "tripe" also used as a single-word exclamation?

Tags: exclamatives

I'd like to know whether a construction with "Tripe!" as for example in

> "He is very active on StackExchange!" "Tripe! He doesn't even know about the existence of StackExchange!"

is possible and common. So far I've only seen "tripe" in exclamations with other words ("This is utter tripe!" etc.)

The dictionaries I've consulted haven't answered that for me, and search engines ignore the exclamation mark, which makes it hard to find any examples.

EDIT: I've added a wrong statement before the "Tripe!" to make it clearer.

Comment: I have never heard of ‘tripe’ being used that way. But you could certainly say ‘Tripe!’ in the same way you would yell ‘Lies!’, when someone says a blatant lie in front of you. If you hear someone say something you consider to be utter nonsense, you could say ‘Tripe!’.

Comment: Yes, the "If you hear someone say something you consider to be utter nonsense" situation is indeed what I had in mind. I've edited my post to make this clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on that "**[tripe](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tripe)**" is an informal word for *ideas, suggestions, or writing that are stupid, silly, or have little value* and is closely related to the meanings of "**crap**", "**bullshit**", "**nonsense**", "**lies**", "**bosh**", "**hogwash**", it can be used in such a way.

Frankly speaking, many such words, expletive or not, can be used standalone with an exclamation mark.

- ***Bullshit***! I didn't do it! or *That's **bullshit**! I didn't do it!*
- ***Crap***! What in the heavens happened here?
- ***Lies***! I've never told him that! or *That's **lies**! I've never told him that!*
- ***Nonsense***! This can't be true!
- ***Tripe***! That wasn't so!

Consider this:

> The exclamation mark is used to express exasperation, astonishment, or surprise, or to emphasise a comment or short, sharp phrase. In professional or everyday writing, exclamation marks are used sparingly if at all.

Comment: Thanks. My question aimed at the vernacular usage and not writing, so that part was clear anyway.